# Error in display while trying to intergate a Wordpress platform to another Wordpress platform

Tags: php, wordpress, migration, integration

**Task:**

My goal is taking a Wordpress platform hosted in A and integrating to another Wordpress platform hosted in B, by migrating it to host B and linking its database.

for example i have

```
testsite1.com 
testsite2.com
```

**Updates**

1. List item

and i want to migrate testsite2 to testsite1 so that

```
testsite1.com/testsite2 = testsite2.com
```

**Approach**

- downloaded source code and database from testsite2
- uploaded source code to *testsite1* server via FTP
- imported database2 to *testsite1* server
- linked database2 to source by configuring wp-config.php

**Result**

expected result when you type testsite1.com/testsite2 should be [this](https://snipboard.io/LENYiH.jpg)

result is [this](https://snipboard.io/vTjkMw.jpg)

any ideas about how to fix this?

**Updates:**

1. Changed home-url and site-url in the database. Now The homepage is like that snipboard.io/iGL4Sy.jpg and I when click in whatever page I get this snipboard.io/qpSsHb.jpg. Checked the database and the data that need to be there are there.

Comment: Did you also change wp options table in database?  Site url and site home?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In wp-config file change correct database details.

Then,change site-url and site-home-url in wp-option table in database

Comment: I did add the correct database... I created a new one then imported the database and then configured wp-config to open it...
Any clue where site-url and site-home-url might be here https://snipboard.io/JeWVIH.jpg

Comment: drgc_options  in your screenshot is a option table.

Comment: It is better but still i got issues

The homepage is like that https://snipboard.io/iGL4Sy.jpg
And I when click in whatever page I get this  https://snipboard.io/qpSsHb.jpg

Comment: I think there must be a error in your  .htaccess file

Comment: https://snipboard.io/pXHPSa.jpg
can u spot any?
or what kind of error in that file could it be?

Comment: Did you change both site_url and  home url  to your website url?

Comment: yes i did change them

Comment: In drgc_options table?

Comment: yes exactly there.
option name -> site-url and home

Comment: do you know if I can access cpanel to create changes in the content of the integrated platform?